# How do I share my Linux folders with a Windows computer?

Tags: windows-7, linux, network-shares, samba

I have a computer running Ubuntu 10.10 32-bit with Gnome and another computer running Windows 7 64-bit. How can I share folders between these? I can use Samba to view my Windows shares, if I specify the IP address by going to the "Connect to Server..." option in the Places menu. Going to "Network" in Nautilus and trying to open "Windows Network" fails because it could not retrieve the share list from the server.

MY question, though, is how can I set up Samba (or some other software) such that my Windows box will be able to see my shared folders? And also, what is the difference between Samba and Samba4 (because both are in the repositories).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Samba is 3.5.6. An alpha version of 4.0.0 is available.

To share some folders with Windows PC's I would read the [Samba examples](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-Guide/simple.html) or the [Samba HOWTOs](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/FastStart.html)

If you prefer a web-based GUI tool, I'd look at the [SWAT HOWTOs](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/SWAT.html#id2682237)

Comment: Thanks, I will use the "samba" package available from the repository.

Comment: The repo tells me that SWAT is no longer actively maintained and not very secure, so I am hesitant to use it.

Comment: @AniDev I mean the communication is not encrypted so that is basic reason.